# Объясните как определить количество натуральных значений n из отрезка [1; 1000], для которых сумма цифр значения F(n) равна 24

Tags: python

[image: Я лишь смог написать самое начало]
Алгоритм вычисления значения функции F(n), где n – натуральное число, задан следующими соотношениями:

```
F(n) = n*n + 4*n + 3, при n > 25
F(n) = F(n+1) + 2*F(n+4), при n ≤ 25, кратных 3
F(n) = F(n+2) + 3*F(n+5), при n ≤ 25, не кратных 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    n += sum(map(int, str(F(i))) == 24

print(n)
```